# Prove that a transcendental entire function with period $\alpha >0$ has infinitely many fixpoints.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f$ is a transcendental entire function such that $f(z+\alpha) = f(z)$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, ($\alpha>0$), prove that $f(z) = z$ has infinitely many solutions in $\mathbb{C}$.

$g(z) = f(z) - z$ is also a transcendental and entire function, and by Picard's Great Theorem $g$ takes every value infinitely often with at most one exception. What I'm having problems with is proving that $0$ can't be the exception. Any help appreciated!

Comment: is there any periodic non-transcendental entire function ?

Comment: @mercio Constant functions are non-transcendental and periodic, but they are the only ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $g(z+a) = f(z+a)-(z+a) = f(z)-z-a = g(z) - a$.

Assume that $g(z) = 0$ only has finitely many solutions. Then, by Picard, $g(z) = a$ has infinitely many solutions, say $z_1, z_2, \ldots$. Hence
$$
g(z_j+a) = g(z_j) - a = 0
$$
for every $z_j$, which is a contradiction.